# Performance issues with HTML5 mobile game

Tags: android, ios, html, air, adobe

We start developing a simple mobile game with HTML5 but we're having second thoughts about our decision. 
When we've added some simple animations using CSS3, these animations work very slowly to not at all on some android devices, and on iOS they run faster but not fast enough.

Do you think there's a way to dramatically improve (simple) graphic performance on HTML5?
We're a bit confused now, as much as we'd hate to lose all the work we've put in this so far, it's better to stop now than in a month or two. The app we're developing is similar in style to Song Pop and now that we know that they have developed their apps (iOS, Android and facebook) using Adobe AIR, we were thinking that might be an alternative. I wanted to ask you if you think we need to abandon HTML5 and develop the game using Adobe AIR or maybe go native (something we're really trying to avoid as we want to launch on all platforms within a reasonable time)?

Comment: I'd go the `Adobe Air` route...

Comment: HTML5 still has a way to go as a standard and especially as a platform with any kind of realistic performance.  I would never recommend it as a gaming platform unless you are just making Snake.  Go with Adobe, and while you are at it check out Starling (an AS3 engine for OpenGL) http://gamua.com/starling/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to go native or use adobe air which translates it into native(sort of).
That way you can implement hardware accelleration and get good performance even on low spec CPU's.

The problem with HTML5 is that there are many layers between the app and input and cpu processing. There are checks, double checks, permission layers, script code processing into cpu understandable instructions which all adds to the delay. With an native app you get direct access to everything and cut away with the script processing.

Even facebook is switching from HTML5 to native http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57511142-93/html5-is-dead-long-live-html5/

Use html for a demo of sorts, so people can get a sniff without having to download, but don't use it for a quickly responsive interaction dependant game.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert your web app into a native app before you decide to translate the code into another language. There are programs around that do this, but I've never used them.

http://mashable.com/2010/08/11/cross-platform-mobile-development-tools/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Its a tortuous debate which route to take.

See the opinions here on [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/What-do-you-guys-think-22352.S.166429949).

Also I've noticed the featured games on the [PhoneGap website](http://phonegap.com/app/feature/) aren't very interactive / game like compared to [Adobe AIR app examples](http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=4536).

Which route did you take in the end? I have a fairly simple [flash app](http://gridclub.com/radius/) I want to deploy to multiple platforms but can't decide which route. Native or AIR or HTML5!